# get current width after resize / setTimeout

Tags: jquery, live, settimeout, onresize

i am trying to get the new browser width after resizing. 
i have tried all..bind, live, resize, now setTimeout. i am not good at jquery but i can understand some.
i hoped someone here might give a hand.
this is my code

```
function myfunction() {

         var w = ($(".wrap").innerWidth());
         var m = ($(".module").outerWidth(true));
         var total = parseInt(w/m);
         var newwrap = total * m;


         $(".wrap").css("width",newwrap);

 }; myfunction(jQuery)



$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout("myfunction()",100)
});
```

i want to make the function run every time the width is changed, after resizing browser. or get the new width after resizing.

thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this function you wrote, to be called on onresize event of the body.

e.g

```
<body onresize="myFunction();">
<!-- your content -->
</body>
```

Comment: oo nice! but it says in console " myFunction is not defined ". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: even I am not that expert in jquery. And I don't know why that statement `myFunction(jQuery)` you have wrote after myFunction definition ends. Maybe that is reason. Just write that function in script and it should be called on onresize. You can refer to this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Comment: works with console.log('text'); but it does not work with my function. earlier it was a misspell, but now everything is okay in console, just function not working. i had a look in w3s, but it's quite brief. anyways, thank you for the idea.

Comment: no errors, just not triggering the function. for example if i refresh the entire page it works.

Comment: are u sure, it does not even trigger. Try writing some variables inside console.log along with some random text like `console.log("here >>> w is: ",w," m is: ",m)`. See if it's printing. Because, it should at least call the function.

Comment: `<body onresize="console.log($('body').width())">` with this i get 753 in console and if i drag the browser it stays the same. :\

Comment: can u briefly explain, what you want to do in your myFunction? what is the element with wrap and module class name?

Comment: I just tried this...
`<body onresize="getResize();">` as event call. and this function...`function getResize() {
 var w = ($(".box").innerWidth());
    var m = ($(".shadow1").outerWidth(true));
    var total = parseInt(w/m);
    var newwrap = total * m;
 console.log(newwrap);
}` And I am able to see new values for newwrap variable on every resize.

Comment: the wrap is the full wrap. that is 100%. the module is a box = 217px. when i resize the browser, i want that the modules are centered. but if i have space for 2 and half boxes (434px + 100px) means that i will have a white space in the right part. so i want the wrap to have the exact size of the fitting boxes. i have 10 boxes, if the windows is small i want 2 boxes on each row, so 5 rows. is it more or less clear? is it okay if we talk here?

Comment: in brief: i want the new width of .wrap to be updated according to how many boxes would fit inside. and no extra space.

Comment: I MADE IT: `function getResize() { 

 var w = ($("body").innerWidth()); 
 var m = ($(".module").outerWidth(true)); 
 var total = parseInt(w/m); 
 var newwrap = total * m; 

 $(".wrap").css("width", newwrap);
  
}`

Answer (score 4):

i am not sure what you want but this may help

```
width = 0;
function myfunction() {
  //your code to calculate width  or use $(window).width();
  width = 100;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(myfunction);
});
```

Comment: what i want to achieve is the function to calculate or run every time the width is changed, therefore i used either resize, either setTimeout. i tried your code, but it still doesn't change. Maybe I am doing something wrong ... :(

Comment: use callbacks for resize function